# System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: 'Unable to set field/property on entity type System.Collections.Generic.HashSet' with EntityFramework 6.4.4

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Whenever I execute DBContext.SaveChanges()
I get this error

```
Unable to set field/property MIXTURE on entity type System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[Wrap.DataAccessDapper.EF.STABILITY_ISSUES, Wrap.DataAccessDapper, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].
```

I've tried changing it back and forth between ICollection HashSet in the declaration and between HashSet and List in implementation of STABILITY_ISSUES in the MIXTURE class.

Here's a part of the MIXTURE class

```
public MIXTURE()
        {
            this.COMPOUND = new HashSet<COMPOUND>();
            this.STABILITY_ISSUES = new HashSet<STABILITY_ISSUES>();
        }
        public int MIXTURE_ID { get; set; }
        ...
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<COMPOUND> COMPOUND { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<STABILITY_ISSUES> STABILITY_ISSUES { get; set; }
```

And here's the STABILITY_ISSUES class

```
public partial class STABILITY_ISSUES
    {
        public int MIXTURE_ID { get; set; }
        public string STABILITY_ISSUES1 { get; set; }
    
        public virtual MIXTURE MIXTURE { get; set; }
    }
```

The table STABILITY_ISSUES in the database has no primary key, it has a foreign key to MIXTURE on MIXTURE_ID

the reason for all caps is probably because this database was migrated from an old Oracle DB to SQL Server not too long ago.
Entity Framework was placed over the Database to replace NHibernate which has been in use for many years.

I've seen at least another post regarding this issue, but it was for an older version of EntityFramework, and the issue was not identical to this one. and there were no satisfactory answers on that post.

Comment: You need a PK set with Identity on the STABILITY_ISSUES table.

Comment: I'll try adding it then, do I need to add it anywhere  else than in that class? I'd rather not do a whole scaffolding for this

Comment: sorry, didn't change anything, I added STABILITY_ISSUES_ID as per the naming standard and set identity and primary key on the column